# Js Dom: Find an element where the class is similar to, or includes substring

Tags: javascript, html, dom, document

I have a specific wrapper element where the *class* has a specific name *included*, alongside with a random id. Example `wp-rgtayfu-fxyjzw-wrapper`. The class will always contain the `wrapper` substring. There is only one element in the document where the class contains `wrapper`.

How can I find it?
(Or how can I query an element by class, using only a substring part of it?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use this CSS Selector.

> [attribute*="value"]

It will select element with a class attribute that contains the specified "value":

```
const targetElement = document.querySelector('[class*="wrapper"]')
```

Answer (score 0):

It is better to separate the part of class you need using space. It will appear separately in classList property and document.getElementsByClassName can find it

The resulting class will be `wp-rgtayfu-fxyjzw wrapper` or `wp rgtayfu fxyjzw wrapper`

If you dont want to change the class, you can run a regex through the entire DOM, but it is really bad idea.